# Como sempre retornar a mesma View, independente do Controller e da Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Criei uma *View* chamada `Manutencao` que exibe uma página de manutenção. E sempre que o Index for chamado eu exibo ela.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Manutencao");
    }
}
```

No ASP.NET MVC 5 como faço para sempre, independente de qualquer *Action* ou *Controller* retornar a View "Manutenção" ? Assim eu evito repetição da linha `return View("Manutencao")` em todas as *Action* (tem umas 80).

Preciso disso porque vou deixar a página offline durante o fim de semana para uma migração de DNS ou seja, preciso que sempre retorne essa página até que eu finalize essa migração.

Comment: Depende muito do que você quer fazer. Se quer sempre mostrar isso, independentemente de qualquer coisa, pode simplesmente trocar o roteamento para sempre redirecionar para uma _action_ que retorne esta _view_. Se você precisa fazer isso de acordo com alguma condição, talvez seja melhor implementar um filtro, ou algo do gênero. Sem mais detalhes sua pergunta fica muito ampla.

Comment: @LINQ editei explicando, esse é o objetivo

Comment: A resposta do Maniero serve então.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti A outra opção que eu postei também não ser viu? Se serviu posso desenvolver mais.

Answer (score 2):

Com informações adicionais parece que é mais ou menos isto:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new CheckForDownPage());
    }
    //o resto do global asax
}
public sealed class CheckForDownPage : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Down.htm");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path) && IpAddress != "1.2.3.4") {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Down.htm");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10451043/221800).

Não parece que é isso que que mesmo. Se não resolver eu apago aqui.

Não sei se é a melhor opção mas achei isto:

```
routes.MapRoute("Offline", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {
        action = "Offline",
        controller = "Home",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
    new { constraint = new OfflineRouteConstraint() });
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582113/221800). Tem algumas opções lá.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/SameView.cs).

Tem [outra solução proposta](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/how-to-take-a-asp-net-mvc-web-site-down-for-maintenance/) que pode servir para cenários comais complexos. Pode ser o que deseja, mas pense bem se precisa mesmo de tudo isso, a pergunta não parece precisar.

Comment: quando eu entro na url "http://localhost:54350" me retorna a Action manutenção(no exemplo a "Offline"), mas quando eu entro em "http://localhost:54350/Home/Index" ele me retorna a Action "Index" normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

Leonardo,

Você pode criar um action filter para interceptar todos os requests quando a aplicação está em modo manutenção.

O Link abaixo mostra como fazer isso.

https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/take-your-asp-net-mvc-application-offline-via-a-global-attribute